# Resources for CNN example with Keras

Tags: deep-learning, keras, cnn, computer-vision, convolutional-neural-network

Please provide me with excellent resources to learn deep learning with Keras, imbalance images classes and using **imageGenerator**, Transfer learning with Keras.

Thank you

Comment: Take a look at [here](https://github.com/ChristosChristofidis/awesome-deep-learning).